# Optimized way of fetching parents with only latest child using django ORM

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlite, django-models

We want to fetch parent child in such a way that it gives me latest 10 parents with each having only one latest child record.

**For example:**

```
Category
- id
- name
- created_date

Item
- id
- name
- category
- created_date
```

Using above specified model structure, I would like to fetch latest 10 categories along with latest child item for each category.

With only one query to the server I would like to access all the data.

```
Category1.name, Category1.id, LatestItemForCat1.name, LatestItem1ForCat1.created_date
Category2.name, Category2.id, LatestItemForCat2.name, LatestItem1ForCat2.created_date
Category3.name, Category3.id, LatestItemForCat3.name, LatestItem1ForCat3.created_date
```

What is the optimized way to achive this using django ORM.

This can be achived with the following sql query. I would prefer to use django ORM for solving this problem. Or better sql query.

```
select c.name, c.id, i.name, i.created_date
from
    category c
inner join
    item i
on c.id = i.category_id
where i.id = (select id from item order by created_date desc limit 0,1)
limit 10
```

Comment: You have a lot of tags on this question.  Do you want the answer as a MySQL query, a SQLite query, or a series of Django functions?

Comment: Does "only one latest child record" mean you only want to show categories that have only one child or do you just need to get the latest child?

Comment: I have edited the question to answer your queries, please provide the answer if you know it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can resort to raw SQL, and your query looks fine (just lacks an "order by c.created_date desc" before the limit in the end.

The subquery in the raw SQL solution is not much better than having a method returning the 10 last entries in the Category model, something like this (untested) sample:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    ...
    def last10items(self):
        return self.item_set.order_by('-created_date')[:10]
```

We are talking about 100 records maximum, I would not worry about efficiency because subsequent queries are like to hit the cache (there are several layers of cache: django, database and OS). This way you can pass the last 10 categories and call last10items from the template:

```
{% for category in categories %}
  ...
  {% for item in category.last10items %}
      ...
```

I'm sure some jerk will downvote me for saying this: **do not try to optimize something unless you need to**. In many situations I was surprised how wrong I was about efficiency of one approach over another until profiling the code. Read "[Python Patterns - An Optimization Anecdote](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/)".

Comment: Very good reply Paulo, thanks a lot, and here is my up vote for you. However i still feel that there should be a better answer for this question, will wait for that for some more time before accepting this as an answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting the items for each category you will have to hit the database for every category once, so it is better to do it the other way round and use `select_related` which will get you the category that belongs to the item without an extra hit:

```
items = Item.objects.order_by('-category__created_date', '-created_date').select_related()
i = 0
cat = None
for item in items:
    if item.category != cat:
        print "%s: %s" % (item.category, item)
        cat = item.category
        i += 1
    if i == 10:
        break
```

I added a for-loop with a counter to only display 10 categories with ONE item, I do not think it's possible to limit this via the ORM if doing it this way!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Regarding this approach, I really don't understand whether this is a right approach or not. The thing which I didn't like is we have to manually loop until latest 10 categories are found. If a category has got 100s of items in under its umbrella, just think how many iteration will be there?

Comment: @software enthusiastic: i'm still not sure if i got the problem right, if i look at the sql that you posted right now: the sql will not give you the ten latest categories, but the ten latest items with their category (so if they would have the same category, the same category would show up more than once). is this what you want? if yes i can edit my post to fit this!

Comment: Yeah, but those categories should be unique. According to your code if we we consider items first and its associated category, to get the next unique category we will have to iterate, fetch and skip the items with considered categories.